# How to print Escape Sequence characters in Swift?

Tags: swift

Sorry if the title is not clear.

What I mean is this:
If I have a variable, we'll call that a, with a value of "Hello\nWorld", it would be written as

```
var a = "Hello\nWorld
```

And if I were to print it, I'd get

```
Hello
World
```

How could I print it as:

```
Hello\nWorld
```

Comment: You would have to write a function to return a string with all the  "\" characters escaped by inserting another "\" in the string wherever the newline character was found.

Comment: you need to escape the back slash. Hello\\nWorld

Comment: Strings with escape sequences, such as `\n`, are not "raw" strings. They are strings expressed in Swift syntax for string literals. Escape sequences are translated by the compiler. There is no built-in functionality to escape back a string.

Comment: Please clarify your goal here. Are you simply referring to printing with `print` for debugging purposes? Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: `print(a.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\\n"))`

Comment: *If* this is for debugging purposes then `print(a.debugDescription)` would do the job.

Comment: @MartinR TIL. That's a good one to know about.

Comment: Or `debugPrint(a)` :)

Comment: @Hamish https://stackoverflow.com/a/71045117/2303865

Answer (score 10):

I know this is a little old however I was looking for a solution to the same problem and I figured out something easy.

If you're wanting to print out a string that **shows the escape characters** like "\nThis Thing\nAlso this"

> print(myString.debugDescription)

Comment: This is pretty close to what OP asked but it will print the double quotes as well

Answer (score 7):

Here's a more complete version of @Pedro Castilho's answer.

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    static let escapeSequences = [
        (original: "\0", escaped: "\\0"),
        (original: "\\", escaped: "\\\\"),
        (original: "\t", escaped: "\\t"),
        (original: "\n", escaped: "\\n"),
        (original: "\r", escaped: "\\r"),
        (original: "\"", escaped: "\\\""),
        (original: "\'", escaped: "\\'"),
    ]

    mutating func literalize() {
        self = self.literalized()
    }

    func literalized() -> String {
        return String.escapeSequences.reduce(self) { string, seq in
            string.replacingOccurrences(of: seq.original, with: seq.escaped)
        }
    }
}

let a = "Hello\0\\\t\n\r\"\'World"
print("Original: \(a)\r\n\r\n\r\n")
print("Literalized: \(a.literalized())")
```

Comment: Nice one. I wouldn't have thought of encoding the list of escape sequences into the `String` class itself. :)

Comment: This fails for `"\0\\"` and `"\\\0"`. Solution is to change the order in the escapeSequences array.

Comment: Not sure if [escaped(asASCII:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar/2906186-escaped) was available almost 5 years ago but it is been available since iOS 8.0+ / Xcode 9. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71045117/2303865)

Comment: Actually it was released a few months later `12 Sep 2017`

Answer (score 2):

You can't, not without changing the string itself. The `\n` character sequence only exists in your code as a representation of a newline character, the compiler will change it into an actual newline.

In other words, the issue here is that the "raw" string is the string with the actual newline.

If you want it to appear as an actual `\n`, you'll need to escape the backslash. (Change it into `\\n`)

You could also use the following function to automate this:

```
func literalize(_ string: String) -> String {
    return string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\\n")
                 .replacingOccurrences(of: "\t", with: "\\t")
}
```

And so on. You can add more `replacingOccurrences` calls for every escape sequence you want to literalize.

Answer (score 1):

If "Hello\nWorld" is literally the string you're trying to print, then all you do is this:

```
var str = "Hello\\nWorld"
print(str)
```

I tested this in the Swift Playgrounds!

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but the answer to this question is to map the String `UnicodeScalarView` `Unicode.Scalar` elements converting them to escaped ascii strings. Then you can simply join back the string:

```
extension Unicode.Scalar {
    var asciiEscaped: String { escaped(asASCII: true) }
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var asciiEscaped: String {
        unicodeScalars.map(\.asciiEscaped).joined()
    }
}
```

---

```
print("Hello\nWorld".asciiEscaped)   // Hello\nWorld
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use double \

```
var a = "Hello\\nWorld"
```