# Swift String including Special Characters

Tags: swift, string, nsstring, foundation, nsstringencoding

I have a user enter a multi string in an NSTextView.

```
var textViewString = textView.textStorage?.string
```

Printing the string ( `print(textViewString)` ), I get a multi-line string, for example:

```
hello this is line 1 

and this is line 2
```

I want a swift string representation that includes the new line characters. For example, I want `print(textStringFlat)` to print:

```
hello this is line 1\n\nand this is line 2
```

What do I need to do to `textViewString` to expose the special characters?

Comment: Replace `\n` with `\\n`. But that only handles the newlines. What other special characters do you want to handle?

Comment: Oh, duh! Thanks! My brain wasn't working there for a second. If you want to write that as an answer, I will approve as correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484860/how-to-print-escape-sequence-characters-in-swift (there is an answer showing also all the escaped sequences if needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to replace the newlines with the literal characters `\` and `n` then use:

```
let escapedText = someText.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\\n")
```

Comment: That is manually replacing and injecting. I thought there should be easier way?